Normal forms of nilpotent matrices over RINGs - Jordan, Smith, etc..
Consider a nilpotent matrix over say Z or C[z], or more general rings (NOT fields).
What is known about their normal forms ? To what extent results over fields can be extended to rings ?
Over field one can conjugate nilpotent matrix to Jordan normal form and actually field need not to be algebraically closed. So passing from ring to  fraction field, we can find conjugating matrices -    however it is not clear for me can we  choose these matrices to be from the initial ring, not field. Even if we relax Jordan form to be just upper diagonal - not requiring standard Jordan cell structure of the matrix.
Concerning Smith normal formal - I have even less intuition.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form

Smith Normal Form in Combinatorics
Richard P. Stanley
https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.00166

On the Smith normal form of the
Varchenko matrix∗
Tommy Wuxing Cai
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347091204_On_the_Smith_normal_form_of_Varchenko_matrix
ON SMITH NORMAL FORMS OF q-VARCHENKO MATRICES
NAOMI BOULWARE, NAIHUAN JING, KAILASH C. MISRA
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2208.00303

https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00922
The Smith Normal Form of a Matrix Associated with Young's Lattice
Tommy Wuxing Cai, Richard P. Stanley
We prove a conjecture of Miller and Reiner on the Smith normal form of the operator DU associated with a differential poset for the special case of Young's lattice. Equivalently, this operator can be described as ∂∂p1p1 acting on homogeneous symmetric functions of degree n.

"Richard (Stanley) also has some slides regarding SNF."
https://math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/transparencies/seattle2016.pdf
https://mathoverflow.net/a/469659/10446

Smith normal form answers a completely different question from Jordan normal form, it considers matrices up to both left and right multiplication by invertible matrices rather than up to conjugacy. Which one do you care about?

@QiaochuYuan about all - any info - welcome
